# PHP dependency injection return type, method chaining

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Is it possible to dictate the return type of a method in PHP?

For instance I have the ImageInterface and it has the methods:

- resize($w, $h)
- setPath($path)
- getContents()

I have a concrete class that utilizes the PHP library intervention.  In the resize method I call the resize from intervention and then return $this at the end of the method...

```
function resize($w, $h) {
    $this->image->resize($w, $h);
    return $this;
}
```

Doing so allow me to chain resize() and getContents() so I can do a quick $image->resize(400, 100)->getContents(), rather than having two separate statements.

Is it possible to indicate/constrain the return type of resize() to the type of ImageInterface?  Right now it resolves at run time correctly but the IDE doesn't know that we're allowed to chain setPath and getContents. Additionally, it doesn't force future implementation of ImageInterface to this style, which could cause problems.

Comment: As of PHP7 you can declare the return type. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: I think this is really up to you to mod you IDE rule. PHP7 syntax for IDE's will be along soon but it does not seem to be here quite yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHPDoc annotations** to declare return types (and many other things...). To make it work, you will also have to use an IDE that supports these annotations (like NetBeans, PHPStorm, etc). Quick example:

```
/**
 * Describe what this method does.
 *
 * @param int $w This is the desired width in pixels.
 * @param int $h This is the desired height in pixels.
 * @return ImageInterface
 */
function resize($w, $h) {
 ...
}
```

More details here: [PSR-5: PHPDoc](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#715-return)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I knew that this was an option but I was really looking for a way to do this programmatically rather than through the annotations.  The reason I wanted to do it via PHP code was to force future implementations to return their instance, so the services could be swapped out without breaking code that utilized them.